# Is it possible to filter on multiple map values in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Some time ago, Firebase introduced a new database called [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). I am trying to migrate my project's [Realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) database to the new one. One of the drawbacks in the **Realtime** database is that it doesn't allow query on multiple fields. As far as I understand, the same applies for **Firestore** (more or less). But, I am trying to understand if it is possible to filter on multiple values inside of a property which is of type **Map**.

For example,

```
field1: "Some string"
field2: "456"
field3: {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
}
```

Here, it is possible to execute compound queries as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

So, I could execute:

```
let query = ref.where('field1', '==', 'Some string').where('field2', '==', '456');
```

But, how can I achieve the same with regard to the properties inside **field3**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare subfields, use dot notation.

So:

```
let query = ref.where('field3.key1', '==', 'value1').where('field3.key2', '==', 'value2');
```